# Custom event handler in Javascript

Tags: javascript, object-oriented, event-handling, observer-pattern

In my web projects I often need a simple way to trigger callbacks defined somewhere else. Leaving jQuery finally behind me, I was missing their simple event system and tried to create my own. I'd like to know if this is a good implementation since I am not that proficient with Javascript yet.

```
function Events ()
{
    /**
     * handlers for an event
     *
     * @var {object}
     */
    this.stack = {}


    /**
     * on function.
     * adds a callback to an event stack
     * 
     * @param {string} event       the event to subscribe to
     * @param {function} callback  the event callback to subscribe
     *
     * @return void
     */
    this.on = function (event, callback)
    {
        // if there is no callback registered for this event yet,
        // create an array for this event
        if (! this.stack.hasOwnProperty(event)) {
            this.stack[event] = []
        }

        // push the event callback to the handler stack
        this.stack[event].push(callback)
    }


    /**
     * off function.
     * removes a callback from an event stack
     * 
     * @param {string} event       the event to unsubscribe from
     * @param {function} callback  the event callback to unsubscribe
     *
     * @return {bool}              whether the callback was removed or not
     */
    this.off = function (event, callback)
    {
        // if the event does not exist, return false
        if (! event in this.stack) return false

        // iterate over handlers, remove the callback in question
        this.stack[event] = this.stack[event].filter(
            function(item) {
                if (item !== callback) {
                    return item
                }
            }
        )

        return true
    }


    /**
     * trigger function.
     * calls all registered callbacks for an event
     * 
     * @param {string} eventName  the event to trigger callbacks for
     * @param {mixed} data        optional data to hand over to the callbacks
     * 
     * @return {bool}             whether the event has been fired
     */
    this.trigger = function (event, data)
    {
        // use an empty object if no data given
        var data = (typeof data === 'undefined') ? {} : data;

        // the event does not exist.
        if (! this.stack.hasOwnProperty(event)) return false

        // iterate over all callbacks, run them as expected
        for (var i = 0; i < this.stack[event].length; i++) {

            // @TODO: the scope should maybe be modifyable, even though
            //        this would require to specify a scope parameter
            //        for every event trigger...
            this.stack[event][i].call(window, event, data)
        }

        return true
    }
}
```

The `Events` class can later be instantiated and used in other objects like so:

```
// ...

this.eventHandler = new Events

this.eventHandler.on('testEvent', function(event, data) {
    console.log(event + ' fired! Data: ' + data)
})

this.eventHandler.trigger('testEvent', 'test data') // testEvent fired! Data: test data

// ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overall it looks pretty good. There are a couple of improvements.

- Stylistically, JavaScript doesn't place the `{` character on a new line. You'll see it start on the same line separated by one space:

  ```
  function Events() {
      // ...
  }

  if (condition) {
      // ...
  } else if (condition) {
      // ...
  } else {
      // ...
  }
  ```
- Since you are not using any function closure variables, there is no need to recreate the `on` and `trigger` methods each time the `Events` constructor function is called. Use the `prototype` property instead:

  ```
  function Events() {
      this.stack = [];
  }

  Events.prototype = {
      stack: null,

      constructor: Event,

      on: function (event, callback) {
          // ...
      },

      off: function (event, callback) {
          // ...
      },

      trigger: function (event, data) {
          // ...
      }
  };
  ```
- You could remove the need for the `new` operator with a little constructor function trickery:

  ```
  function Events() {
      if (!(this instanceof Events)) {
          return new Events();
      }

      this.stack = [];
  }
  ```

  This would allow you to generate a new `Events` object by calling `Events()`:

  ```
  Events().on("foo", function(event) {
      // ...
  });
  ```
- The word `Events` makes this seem like a collection of existing events. Really you've created an event dispatcher, and `EventDispatcher` feels like a better name.

Answer (score 2):

I object to your use of `stack`.  In what sense is it a "stack"?  It doesn't maintain stack discipline (you can remove any callback using `off()`, not just the most recently added one), nor do you access them in a last-in, first-out order in `trigger()`.

In other words, it's just an associative array of lists.  Naming it `stack` is misleading and confusing.  I suggest naming it `callbacks`.

Comment: You are absolutely correct. As English is not my mother tongue, sometimes it's difficult to name variables the right way. I used `stack` as the way callbacks are being run is one after another, as they have been added to the stack. Besides, there are no easy ways to move callbacks in the stack.